# Failed to start the Kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code, jupyter-kernel

I am quite new to this, I tried using Jupyter(on VS code) in one of the folders and it works fine but the moment I open a .ipynb file in some other folder it shows a [kernel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dejgv.png)

I think I have not installed it properly, can someone please guide me what to do now ?

Comment: Please, add to the question post the error message in **textual** form. This is **requirement** of the Stack Overflow. Images and links doesn't fulfill that requirement. See also [ask].